# Complicated If statement column format

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting, column-formatting

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and wondered if anyone could help!

I have a SharePoint list (attendance tracking) with 4 date columns:

- Arrival Time (this is filled-in using [Today] by default when the item is created)
- Sign-out
- Sign-in
- Exit Time

And a text column called Status.

I want the Status column to quickly show whether the person is in the building, or out, based on the 4 date columns (e.g. if there is a time/date in the Arrival Time column, but not in Sign-out column then they are in the building.

I am trying to adapt some [json on GitHub](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-list-formatting/blob/master/column-samples/date-check-blank-format/date-check-blank-format.json) but I am really struggling to get the if statements down!

This is ideally what I want to achieve:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your logic and screenshot match? For example, in the 2nd row, Sign-out column has a value, but status is "In"

Comment: The way we use it is a person will arrive (Arrival Time), they might sign-out for a break (Sign-Out Time) and then sign back in (Sign-In Time), then they will leave at the end of they day (Exit Time). So each row is their sign-in's and out's for the day!. On the second row they have signed back in, so they are In (Status) the building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if(Number([$SignOutTime])!=0 && Number([$ExitTime])!=0, 'Out', if(Number([$SignOutTime])!=0 && Number([$SignInTime])==0,'Out',if(Number([$ArrivalTime])==0, 'Out', 'In')))",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "=if(Number([$SignOutTime])!=0 && Number([$ExitTime])!=0,'sp-field-severity--severeWarning',if(Number([$SignOutTime])!=0 && Number([$SignInTime])==0,'sp-field-severity--severeWarning',if(Number([$ArrivalTime])==0, 'sp-field-severity--severeWarning', 'sp-field-severity--good')))"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing, thank you so much! It has totally saved my week, and helped me to understand logic better!